# css fixed position footer print

Tags: html, css, printing

I'd like to print multiple pages each with a different footer (i.e. contained within parent wrapper). 
I can't get it to work...the footer from the 1st page always overflows every other footer (because of fixed positioning)... absolute positioning would be best but there's another problem... you can't tell how long the print page will be so it won't be always positioned at an absolute end of the page.

Here the code that doesn't work...

HTML

```
<div id="wrap">
        <div class="print1">
            <div class="foot">
                foot 1
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="page-break"></div>
        <div class="print2">
            <div class="foot">
                foot 2
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="page-break"></div>
        <div class="print3">
            <div class="foot">
                foot 3
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="page-break"></div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
    #wrap{
height:400px;
width:100%;
}
.print1,.print2,.print3{
height:200px;
border-bottom:1px solid #000;
}
.foot{
display: block;
width:100%;
position:fixed;
bottom:0;
margin-top:-54px;
height:54px;
}
.page-break{
display:block;
page-break-before:always
}
```

It this even possible without JS?

EDIT: z-index doesn't help...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To fix your problem of them not displaying over each other because of position:fixed.  You can do the following:

```
.print1,.print2,.print3
{
  position: relative;
  height: 11in;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  page-break-inside: avoid;
}
.foot
{
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1in;         
}
```

Making the parent div relative and the footer absolute ensures that the footers is at the bottom of each parent div.

To ensure that it is at the bottom of a page we just provide the size of the page (each container .print1, print2 ...) in inches.  Since pixels can't be used because of screen resolution differences, dpi's differing and so forth.

Comment: Specifying height is a problem... because people use different print margin settings (not to mention paper size)...and the it breaks the layout...fixed positioning is the only way I could solve the print layout and margin issues... which your solution breaks...

Comment: Then you will only be able to have one footer - because fixed will display them over each other, like your current example does.  Otherwise absolute with the footer displaying where-ever the div ends is still better than them displaying over each other. (My example without the height specified)

Comment: Sorry but "still better" won't cut it for me... because of other previously mentioned issues... Thanks for your time but this is not the solution I was looking for...

Comment: if the .foot height is known, eg 3cm, you can set the .foot height to -3cm.  Then for an a4 page, you can set the .print1 height to 29-3 -margins = 24cm.